# Can't import cross-sell when cross-sell sku contains space

Tags: magento-1.9, import, cross-sells

In "System, Import/Export, Dataflow Advanced Profiles" I have a profile for importing Cross-sell. It works fine; however when the cross-sell SKU contains space it is not imported. The product itself can contain SKU, but not the associated cross-sell item.

The .csv file looks like this:

```
store;sku;crosssell
admin;DD IN;ES-1,DD OT,LB EB
admin;DD OT;ES-1,ES-2,ES-3
```

...where the first item (DD IN) will only import ES-1 as cross-sell because the other two items fail due to spaces in SKU, while the second item (DD OT) will import all three cross-sell items (ES-1, ES-2, ES-3) because they don't contain space in SKU.

The profile execution log-window does not report any errors.

I've tried to put the sku's within single and/or double quotes, without luck.

Is there any way to bypass this issue?

The XML-script for importing the cross-sell looks like this:

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[import_products_relations.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[;]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_productimportrelations</var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does admin;DD IN;DD OT,ES-1,LB EB import the first cross-sell ? Does admin;DD IN;DD OT works ?

Comment: In the example .csv above; the first line will only import the first cross-sell item, while the second line will import all three cross-sell items. So it seems like cross-sell items with space in the SKU is ignored.

Comment: Can you still try what I am asking ? It can lead to a solution but I do not have time to try it myself.

Comment: Ah sorry @Christophe, I misunderstood you. 
admin;DD IN;DD OT,ES-1,LB EB  imports the second cross-sell item (ES-1) only,
admin;DD IN;DD OT does not import anything.
Any cross-sell item with space in SKU seems to be ignored, others are imported (regradless of order)

Comment: if you change parse by any other method of app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php (maybe getCsvString for the method). Sorry, that's my final guess, I miss knowledge of this functionality.

Comment: Unfortulatley I don't feel confident digging into core code, so my workaround for this import was to temporary rename the SKU of the involved cross-sell items (in this case only 5 items), do the import, and rename them back. I could do this because the problem didn't affect all the items in the 'sku' colum, only the few cross-sell items with space in the 'crosssell' colum.  

I've not added this workaround as a answer to my question, because it's not really a solution to the problem.